# Missing on-screen keyboard for Bitlocker

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, bitlocker, tablet

I have a Lenovo Yoga tablet that identifies on the command prompt as **20C30024US** with the `csproduct get name` command. It runs Windows 8 x64 Enterprise with Bitlocker enabled. This tablet has no external keyboard. It has all of the latest Microsoft and Lenovo updates installed, including BIOS update.

Sometimes, when booting up, Bitlocker does not display the on-screen keyboard and nothing I do can bring it up. The only workaround is to reboot and hope the keyboard is there.

Anyone else experienced this or know of a solution? Thanks.